# Fetch Product Info from website using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to extract data from Amazon.in into an Excel using VBA. So for any product listed on Amazon, the Amazon webpage for the same can be accessed using the following link:

[www.amazon.in/dp/B00775Q5PU](http://www.amazon.in/dp/B00775Q5PU)

The no. at the end (starting with B00) is the unique product identification no. Now I have a list of such products and their unique product identification nos. in an Excel sheet. If you now scroll down to the bottom of the Amazon product webpage, the product info is available as shown below:

```
Brand               Samsung
Model               HM 1100
Item Weight         41 g
Product Dimensions  12.8 x 8.8 x 3.8 cm
Item model number   HM 1100
```

I want to extract just the product weight (listed as Item weight) from this website and into the Excel sheet containing the list of products. Can someone please help me with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: This kind of open-ended question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you have attempted to write code and it does not work, show us that and we can help you. As is, this question is too broad and will probably get closed.

Comment: You can for this page only extract easily but as it relies on positional/CSS matching that almost certainly doesn't hold true from page to page any solution given would break pretty quickly. Even parsing for "weight" is no guarantee will be present on each page, and if present, will be the only one present.

Answer (score 0):

*Data* menu - *Import External Data - New Web Query* (**Alt + D - D - W**) and follow the wizard. Select just your table. Select your update options. It will appear where you specify (current cell). Record the steps with Macro Recorder. *Tools* menu *- Macro - Record New Macro* (**Alt + T - M - R**).

Answer (score 0):

http://seotoolsforexcel.com/
this works very well for scraping data, and it has a FREE version!

importxml works very good as well (but it uses google sheets)
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en

I've used them both and when one fails, the other one usually prevails


***Word of Caution***

Amazon frowns highly upon using scrapers on their servers since it takes up substantial resources. Be careful as it may be against their terms of services.

Comment: Excel 2013 and above has the WEBSERVICE and FILTERXML functions, but I am not sure if they work with HTML https://blogs.office.com/2013/03/21/use-webservice-functions-to-automatically-update-excel-2013-spreadsheets-with-online-data/